how i can move collection object on a single axis with geonode with proximity
hii everyone i want to create a wave effect which made out of cube with proximity node Like this istockphoto.com/video/…. problem is this node setup is not working.
here us the node setup

Blender file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/102Z_9FHk03cF7UdciaSe5tVfCPT2xdxh/view?usp=sharing

Can't understand your question. Can you explain what you mean?

@DanielMöller i want to create a wave effect which made out of cube with proximity node Like this https://www.istockphoto.com/video/3d-loopable-abstract-cube-background-animation-gm2104009127-566589464.     problem is this node setup is not working

I think "split to instances" might be the problem. Also, try "reset children" in the collection info, as well as "original" in the object info. It would help if you could edit your question including that extra information you gave, as well as sharing your file (since it's easier for others to test solutions without having to create the whole scene again) - You can use https://blend-exchange.com/ to share the file.

@DanielMöller i tried this but not working for me

This is happening because the origin of all the cubes is at 0,0,0.
So, their position is 0,0,0. The geonodes sees them all at the same place (so all have the same distance to the sphere)
What you need to do is to select every cube in the collection (in object mode), right click, set origin, origin to geometry.
That way, each cube position will be really where they are.
